# Can I edit my boot splash to any picture I want to?

Tags: startup, plymouth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get some nice eye candy themes for Grub?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66183/how-can-i-get-some-nice-eye-candy-themes-for-grub)

I want the very friendly looking old mac face. 
When I boot ubuntu I want this to come up instead of the purple screen as it is now.

I've heard of people doing this but can it be done?

I want a picture similar to this one, with the friendly face and all the icons.

I'm using 11.04 Ubuntu.

[image]